# <noscript> redirect, would it affect search engine optimization?

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine

If i would have such script on website

```
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/Noscript">
</noscript>
```

The content of my /Noscript saying that user cannot properly use web site without JavaScript enabled and  contains information how to turn JavaScript on

So it will redirect each request to  `/Noscript` page if client javascript is disabled.
But it is a bit scary because i think what would happend if search engine bot come to my web site, is it will be redirected to that page was well?

So i mean would it affect SEO(`Bing, Google` etc) somehow ?

Does search engine bots ignored `<noscript>` tags?

Comment: Why would you force _any_ user to a completely separate page, just because they have JS disabled? This sounds like worse UX for them and more maintenance for you.

Comment: @Matt Ball Basically my /Noscript it is page with details how to turn JS on

Comment: This won't work anyway.  *NoScript* blocks such redirects, thank goodness.

Comment: I don't think the web scrabbler will understand the meta and no script tag

Comment: Why wouldn't you just insert a large, obvious banner that "explains how to turn JavaScript on?" Note that the vast majority of browsers have JS on by default, so people who have it turned off **want it turned off.** You're worrying about solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @Brock Adams so search bots ignored `noscript` completely, it is what you saying?

Comment: <noscript>
        <h1>Javascript is required for interactive features on this page. </h1>
</noscript>

I'm pretty sure all browsers that have >1% marketshare enables javascript. If someone has disabled it manually, they know what they are doing.

Comment: Joper, No, I was saying that people who use NoScript are protected from these shenanigans.  How search-engines treat it is subject to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a page from Stack Overflow, and other good sites...

### Don't require javascript for basic operation!

Then gently prod the user:

> "This site requires javascript for full functionality."

[image]

And, yes, having a separate page for non-JS browsers will hurt your SEO.

[Google frowns on having different content for JS and non-JS users, too](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355).

Comment: OK, i think it is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Search engine spiders will not follow META Redirect tags. In addition, using the META Redirect tag forces your visitors to first load the old page, then load the new page, which is a drain on a site with substantial traffic.

Sorry, Forget to paste the reference page:
http://www.seologic.com/faq/url-redirect-script.php

And I think the biggest problem with using this method is that the web page is included in the visitor's page history, and when the user clicks the "back" button and reaches the redirection page again they will be immediately returned to the redirection-target page.

Comment: What do you mean saying `forces your visitors to first load the old page, then load the new page` ?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that "spiders will not follow META Redirect tags"?  This seems to be debated and the search engines themselves are closed lipped (at least as far as I can find, so far).